# how do you get the frequency of the terms generated by tfidf.get_feature_names_out()

Tags: scikit-learn, tfidf

After fitting with tfidf, I'm looking at the features that were generated:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
corpus = [
    'This is the first document.',
    'This document is the second document.',
    'And this is the third one.',
    'Is this the first document?',
]
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
print(vectorizer.get_feature_names_out())
```

but I want to get the frequency of each term or feature as well. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the given example, There are 9 distinct words, which will be printed in your `print` statement. The corpus has 4 sentences, each word will be represented in a row of 4 rows having its frequency, so that `X`, which has the frequency values you are trying to find, will have the shape `(4, 9)`.

If you print `X[0][0]` value, you will get the frequency of the word `and` in the first sentence of the corpus.

Comment: to be clear I'm looking to get the number of times each word appears in the entire corpus